# When passing a Ruby array as an argument, why does `<<` append while `+=` does not?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I ran across an unexpected result when passing an array to a function and the behavior of `<<` vs `+=`.

Can anyone explain why the following 2 programs have different output?

```
def build_results
  result = []

  [1, 2, 3].each { |value| concat_to_array(value, result) }

  result
end

def concat_to_array(value, arr)
  arr << value
end

build_results() # Will return [1,2,3].  As I would expect.
```

vs

```
def build_results
  result = []

  [1, 2, 3].each { |value| add_to_array(value, result) }

  result
end

def add_to_array(value, arr)
  arr += [value]
end

build_results() # Will return [], not what I expected!
```

My understanding is that in Ruby all function arguments are passed by reference, so `arr += [value]` should still be operating on the passed array and append the value.

This is not the case, which tells me I don't understand the difference between `+=` and `<<` in this context.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully first [`ary + other_ary → new_ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-2B). See the **new_ary**. Then [`ary << obj → ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C). See the **ary**.

Comment: It's more like "pass by pointer" than "pass by reference". You're passing the object into the method, not the variable itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference between the `#<<`, and `#+` s that `#<<` is just the `Array`'s instance method, so you just add a value to the specified instance of `Array`

```
arr = []
arr.__id__ # => 68916130
arr << 10
arr.__id__ # => 68916130
```

but in form of `#+` is used assignment operator, which replace reference to a variable with a new instance, and that new instance shall not be passed into uplevel of the `#add_to_array` function.

```
arr = []
arr.__id__ # => 68916130
arr += [10]
arr.__id__ # => 68725310
```

**NOTE:** That `+=` implies the `#+` method plus assignment operator `=`, however [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) interpreter treats it as a specific operator not as a sum.

#### Additionals

The form `arr = arr + [10]` isn't work properly also.

```
def add_to_array(value, arr)
  arr = arr + [value]
end
build_results()
# => []
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  It still seems opposite to what the 'meaning' of that line of code would be!

Comment: @MattRiemer One thing that *will* work is `arr.replace(arr+[value])` because you are keeping the same instance. `arr += [value]` is the same as `arr = arr + [value]` which creates a completely new instance.

Comment: @MattRiemer I've added the update, form `arr = arr + [10]` isn't work also

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, they are alias.

Comment: Excellent explanation, Малъ. @Arup is amazing, as he anticipated a question I had: is `object_id` defined as an alias of `__id__`? Another handy `__xx__` is `__method__` for the current method. Thanks for the Sochi show (but worth $50b? hmmm). [Amusing cover](http://www.poynter.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/newyorker-putin-skating.jpg) on a recent New Yorker magazine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Here is a [proof](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__).. :)

Comment: @Arup, I knew they meant the same, just was wondering which was the alias.  I'm guessing that in most cases, `__xx__` is the non-alias.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that in Ruby all function arguments are passed by reference

No, as you have discovered yourself, Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. That's why you are seeing the result you are seeing.